# where is SP_EXECUTESQL defined?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-executesql

The 'SP_' prefix by convention suggests a **system** stored procedure. But nowhere in my SQL Server instance could I find the [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) stored procedure.

I know it is there because it is used by one of my workplace's legacy code. But where is it? **Where** can I find it using MS SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Where can I find it using MS SQL Server Management Studio?

[image: master --> Programmability --> Extended Stored Procedures --> System Extended Stored Procedures]

It is an extended stored procedure and you can't do anything useful with it having found it though (apart from managing permissions).

Answer (score 3):

master --> Programmability --> Extended Stored Procedures --> System Extended Stored Procedures

Answer (score 3):

It is present there , if you execute this query 
`sp_helptext sp_executesql 
you will get (Server Internal) because "sp_helptext" is a extended stored procedures so you cannot see it. They are processed in a dll rather than TSQL..
Refer this link 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175200%28v=sql.105%29.aspx